Memory Leak while persisting bulk data
I am importing a lot of data from a csv, transform it to list of objects and write it to the database. This is working fine but it seems to have a memory leak.
The problem is that the memory does not get released after the import is done. It is stacking up everytime the import is running until the application runs out of memory. When I run the garbage collector manually (with jcmd  GC.run) the memory is released.
I don't want to run the garbage collector in the code when it's not necessary. I'd rather understand where the flaws of my code is and why the programm can't clear the memory itself.
My code:
fun importData() {
    logger.info("Import started")
    
    transactionTemplate.execute {
        logger.info("Loading Csv1...")
        val c1 = importCsv1() // size: 20.000 elements
        logger.info("Loading Csv2...")
        val c2 = importCsv2() // size: 500.000 elements
        logger.info("Loading Csv3...")
        val c3 = importCsv3() // size: 2.000.000 elements

        logger.info("Deleting Tables...")
        c1Repository.deleteAllInBatch()
        c2Repository.deleteAllInBatch()
        c3Repository.deleteAllInBatch()

        logger.info("Persisting C1...")
        bulkObjectRepository.persist(c1)
        logger.info("Persisting C2...")
        bulkObjectRepository.persist(c2)
        logger.info("Persisting C3...")
        bulkObjectRepository.persist(c3)
        logger.info("Import finished")
    }
    //do some stuff here that must be outside transaction
}

And the BulkObjectRepository:
@Service
class BulkObjectRepository(
    @Value("5000") private val batchSize: Int, 
    private val entityManager: EntityManager
) {
    fun persist(entities: Iterable<Any>) {
        val iterator: Iterator<Any> = entities.iterator()
        for ((i, obj) in iterator.withIndex()) {
            if (i > 0 && i % batchSize == 0) {
                entityManager.flush()
                entityManager.clear()
            }
            entityManager.persist(obj)
        }
        entityManager.flush()
        entityManager.clear()
    }
}

I also tried to use the @Transactional annotation on the method and not use transactionTemplate but it's the same behavior.

When you say the memory is not being released, what specifically do you mean?  Is this from the OS perspective or from JVM heap usage perspective?

I think both. I got a look into the heap with VisualVM and also with "top" on the linux machine which runs it. It seems that the lists are not being garbage collected automatically. They grow bigger every night when the import runs until the application is out of memory. Running GC on the command line releases the memory, but it's not done automatically

So JVM will typically not GC until it needs to.  Unless you're getting actual errors (are you?) I wouldn't worry about this.  JVM will also typically not release memory back to the OS unless you configure it to do so.  I would challenge you to be sure you need this, rather than just wanting the free mem number to go up.

BTW, if a System.gc() frees up the memory, it's not a memory leak.  If your JVM holds a lot of memory for a long time and that causes issues, that may still be a problem for you and you jvm can be tuned, but it's not a leak.  See, for ex, this def: https://www.baeldung.com/java-memory-leaks#what-is-a-memory-leak

@Taylor thanks for that hint. It broke my mind for days now. Setting the jvm -Xmx is resolving the problem. Without boundary the application somehow doesn't get cleaned up until out of memory error. When I set -Xmx objects get garbage collected.

What that does is set an upper limit on overall heap size.  IIRC, if not specified, the heap size defaults to quite a low value, but this is jvm dependent.  I wonder if this was getting specified elsewhere for you (i.e. you're overriding it with a more appropriate value) or if you're on some jvm version that defaults to some huge/unbounded value.  Anyways, glad you got it sorted.
